# Azure functions, azureFunctionsPackage task failing with java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, azure, gradle, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an azure function app which is an EventGridTrigger, and I am using gradle. I can build my code and the tests pass. However, when running the task to **package** my azure functions, the task fails and I get get this exception in terminal:

```
Execution failed for task ':functionsPackage'.
    > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

One of the senior engineers I work with told me he saw the error before, and it was a bug. He said usually it happens with the java 8 streams API lambdas, and I would need to find each lambda and replace with an annoymous class, so I did that. I commented all the azure functions apps code and reintroduced each line of code, piece-by-piece, until I found which one breaks the azureFunctionsPackage task, and I found it to be this method:

```
private boolean isHandledSubject(SchedulerEventSubject schSubject)
    {
        // Handle our subscriber ID
        //if(SubscriberIds.SWITCH_DMS_ID.equals(schSubject.getSubscriberId()))
        //{
        //    return true;
       // }

        // If the subscriber ID is ALL and it's a switch or network element
//        if(SubscriberIds.ALL_ID.equals(schSubject.getSubscriberId()))
//        {
//            return ElementType.SWITCH.equals(schSubject.getElementType()) ||
//                    ElementType.NETWORK.equals(schSubject.getElementType());
//        }
//
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see, even when I completely commented out all of the method body, it breaks the code and causes the NullPointerException, which I'm confused because I expected it to atleast be one of the methods inside? Even if I make the method void or to return true, it still breaks. This method is called 1 time inside my main EventGridTrigger function called **handleEvent** (I didn't write any of this code, so I was hoping to avoid any major changes, to avoid breaking something). I will paste the code below, but has anyone seen this before? I'm a bit perplexed. I made changes to this code base on my own branch, and the develop branch compiles/builds fine.

```
@FunctionName("genericEventHandler")
    public void handleEvent(@EventGridTrigger(name = "event") String content) {
        try {
            if (content == null)
                return;

            ObjectMapper objMap = new ObjectMapper();
            objMap.registerModule(new JodaModule());
            EventGridEvent event = SchedulerIcdKt.fromSchedulerEventJson(content);

            log.info("EventObject {} ", event);

            String schedulerTopic = keyProvider.get(
                    SCHEDULER_EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_FULL_PATH);

            // Check for nulls
            if (isBlank(schedulerTopic) || isBlank(event.topic())) {
                log.error("Event Grid Topic was NULL! KeyVault:{} Event Topic:{}", schedulerTopic, event.topic());
                return;
            }

            // First check if we even have an event from the Scheduler
            if (!event.topic().equalsIgnoreCase(schedulerTopic))
                return;

            SchedulerEventSubject schSubject = new SchedulerEventSubject(event.subject());

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<SchedulerEvent> schedulerEventList = (List<SchedulerEvent>) event.data(); //unsafe cast

            if (!isHandledSubject(schSubject))
                return;

            schedulerEventList.stream().forEach(new Consumer<SchedulerEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(SchedulerEvent schedEvent) {
                    String networkId;
                    SnmpCred cred = new SnmpCred();

                    if (schedEvent.getActionType().equals(SchedulerEventActionType.NetworkCreate)) {
                        NetworkCreate network_create = (NetworkCreate) schedEvent;
                        networkId = network_create.getNetworkId();
                    } else if (schedEvent.getActionType().equals(SchedulerEventActionType.NetworkUpdate)) {
                        NetworkUpdate network_update = (NetworkUpdate) schedEvent;
                        networkId = network_update.getNetworkId();
                    } else {
                        log.info("Unhandled scheduler data: {}", schedEvent);
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        Optional<Network> network = DataGatewayFactory.getInstance().getNetworkCrud().get(networkId);

                        if (!network.isPresent()) {
                            log.error("Error trying to retreive Network with ID {} from the database.", networkId);
                            return;
                        }

                        boolean status;

                        // If Deployment Type is DEMO, ONLY call deployPtpConfigBlob (no switch config)
                        if (network.get().getDeploymentType().equals(DeploymentType.DEMO)) {
                            status = deployPtpConfigBlob(network.get());
                        } else {
                            createOrGetNetworkSnmpPassword(network.get(), cred);

                            if ((status = deploySwitchConfigBlob(network.get(), cred.getAuth(), cred.getPriv()))) {
                                status = deployPtpConfigBlob(network.get());
                            }
                        }

                        // Return the same scheduler subject with the subject Id set to switch dms
                        schSubject.setSubscriberId(SubscriberIds.SWITCH_DMS_ID);
                        EventGridFunctions.this.publishDmsStatus(schSubject, status, schedEvent);
                    } catch (Exception de) {
                        log.error("Exception while trying to retreive the network {}.", networkId, de);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("EventObject {} ", content, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I  was able to "fix" this by commenting all the code in Azure functions leaving the other code in my project uncommented and able to run. I built the project and it was successful. This let me know the problem was 100% with my azure functions.

I then commented all the code out in the azure functions and went line-by-line uncommenting and re-building to see when it would break.

When I hit a method, like the "isHandledSubject" method I posted above, the build would break with the NullPointerException. Even with an empty method body and void as return type. I saw a ClassPath = null when printing out the --scan information when running azureFunctionsPackage class, so I decided to move the method outside this class (i.e. I created a new class called "HelperFunctions.java" and put the methods inside there).

Lo-and-behold the build was successful. I then placed all other methods that were in the same .java files as the Azure functions (EventGridTriggers, QueueTriggers, HttpTriggers etc..) and moved them OUTSIDE the classes in question and put them in the HelperFunctions.java and everything built fine.

I still don't quite understand the basis of this error but the build was also successfully on the cloud (azure devops) so I'm happy :D